# Calling handwritten CUDA kernel with thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

since i needed to sort large arrays of numbers with CUDA, i came along with using thrust. So far, so good...but what when i want to call a "handwritten" kernel, having a thrust::host_vector containing the data?

My approach was (backcopy is missing):

```
int CUDA_CountAndAdd_Kernel(thrust::host_vector<float> *samples, thrust::host_vector<int> *counts, int n) {

 thrust::device_ptr<float> dSamples = thrust::device_malloc<float>(n);
 thrust::copy(samples->begin(), samples->end(), dSamples);

 thrust::device_ptr<int> dCounts = thrust::device_malloc<int>(n);
 thrust::copy(counts->begin(), counts->end(), dCounts);

 float *dSamples_raw = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dSamples);
 int *dCounts_raw = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dCounts);

 CUDA_CountAndAdd_Kernel<<<1, n>>>(dSamples_raw, dCounts_raw);

 thrust::device_free(dCounts);
 thrust::device_free(dSamples);
}
```

The kernel looks like:

```
__global__ void CUDA_CountAndAdd_Kernel_Device(float *samples, int *counts)
```

But compilation fails with:

> error: argument of type "float **" is
>   incompatible with parameter of type
>   "thrust::host_vector> *"

Huh?! I thought i was giving float and int raw-pointers? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the kernel with the name of the function the call is in, not the name of the kernel - hence the parameter mismatch.

Change:

```
CUDA_CountAndAdd_Kernel<<<1, n>>>(dSamples_raw, dCounts_raw);
```

to

```
CUDA_CountAndAdd_Kernel_Device<<<1, n>>>(dSamples_raw, dCounts_raw);
```

and see what happens.

Comment: D'oh! - The error is always by myself, not in the implementation.